# Capybara & Poltergeist will not find my button

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

This seems to be a common asked question, but I feel I have tried absolutely everything now. (find, click_button, locate etc. etc). Nothing works (all listed below)

Seems to be consensus that if the css (e.g. divs out of place) it causes problems from Capybara. so I've now stripped back my html to the absolute bare minimum (below). yet nothing seems to find my confirm button.

I am using zurb foundation, but doesn't seem to be anything that suggests this is at fault.

I'm sure its something simple (It always is!) but damned if I can find…. any thoughts much appreciated?

*html*

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="/css/foundation.css">
    </head>
      <body>
          <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/register_user" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_wizard2" method="post">
            <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
                 <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
                 <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="hvDwKcztZ4jS0KNtRMD324EfTo+eNtHfSZVD/yDWVZc=" />
            </div>
            <input class="button postfix" id="confirm_email_btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
          </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

*generated from rails erb*

```
  <%= form_tag("/register_user", :method => :post, :multipart => true, :id => "form_wizard2") do -%>
                <%= submit_tag "Confirm", :class => "button postfix",  :id => "confirm_email_btn"  %>

   <% end %>
```

*rspec test*

```
 it 'asks an anonymous user for their email address and asks to check inbox', :driver => :poltergeist, :js => true do
   < find test what ever it is >
 end
```

*what I have tried*

*check html*

- puts page.html to check outputs
- save_and_open_page to check html

*Capybara::ElementNotFound Exception*

- find(:xpath,'//a[@id="confirm_email_btn"]')
- all(:xpath,'//a[@id="confirm_email_btn"]').first
- find("#confirm_email_btn")
- find('input#commit')

*breaks poltergeist*

- scoping (seems to break poltergeist)
  within("//form[@id='form_wizard2']") do
  find("//input[@type='submit']").click
  end

*other*

- prefixing all the above with "page."

Comment: I see your XPaths are looking for //a.  But your button is an input.

Have you tried:  find(:xpath,'//input[@id="confirm_email_btn"]') ?

Comment: and there you have it! thanks, spot on… i had originally had a link and updated to an input form. thanks sporkinventor